# Spark: Reading big MySQL table into DataFrame fails

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I'd like to tell in advance that several related questions, like the following, DO NOT address my problems:

- [Spark query running very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693723)
- [Converting mysql table to dataset is very slow...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696455)
- [Spark Will Not Load Large MySql Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141664)
- [Spark MySQL Error while Reading from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126271)

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603351) comes close but the stack-trace is different and it is unresolved anyways. So rest assured that I'm posting this question after several days of (*failed*) solution-hunting.

---

I'm trying to write a job that moves data (once a day) from `MySQL` tables to `Hive` tables stored as `Parquet` / `ORC` files on `Amazon S3`. Some of the tables are quite big: **~ 300M records** with **200 GB+ size** (as reported by `phpMyAdmin`).

Currently we are using `sqoop` for this but we want to move to `Spark` for the following reasons:

- To leverage it's capabilities with `DataFrame API` (in future, we would be performing *transformations* while moving data)
- We already have a *sizeable* framework written in `Scala` for `Spark` jobs used elsewhere in the organization

---

I've been able to achieve this on *small* `MySQL` tables without any issue. But the `Spark` job (that reads data from `MySQL` into `DataFrame`) fails if I try to fetch more than **~1.5-2M records** at a time. I've shown the *relevant portions* of stack-trace below, you can find the complete stack-trace [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvO_iTp-rsuogYYKsM9H3bY077VXQIhp/view?usp=sharing).

```
...
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
...
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
...
org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.taskSummary(OneStageResource.scala:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
...
[Stage 27:>                                                       (0 + 30) / 32]18/03/01 01:29:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 92, ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal, executor 6): java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect key file for table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sql_14ae_5.MYI'; try to repair it
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
...
```

** *This stack-trace was obtained upon failure of moving a **148 GB** table containing **186M** records*

As apparent from (full) stack-trace, the `Spark` read job starts *sulking* with the [false warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635510) of `None.get` error followed by `SQLException: Incorrect key for file..` (which is related to `MySQL`'s [*tmp table* becoming full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090073))

---

Now clearly this can't be a `MySQL` problem because in that case `sqoop` should fail as well. As far as `Spark` is concerned, I'm [*parallelizing* the read operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,columnName:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) by setting `numPartitions = 32` (we use parallelism of 40 with `sqoop`).

From my *limited knowledge* of `Spark` and `BigData`, **148 GB** shouldn't be **overwhelming** for Spark by any measure. Moreover since `MySQL`, `Spark` (`EMR`) and `S3` all reside in same *region* (`AWS` `AP-SouthEast`), so **latency** shouldn't be the **bottleneck**.

---

My questions are:

1. Is `Spark` a suitable tool for this?
2. Could `Spark`'s `Jdbc` *driver* be blamed for this issue?
3. If answer to above question is

   - Yes: How can I overcome it? (alternate driver, or some other workaround)?
   - No: What could be the possible cause?

---

*Framework* Configurations:

- `Hadoop` distribution: **Amazon 2.8.3**
- `Spark` **2.2.1**
- `Hive` **2.3.2**
- `Scala` **2.11.11**

`EMR` Configurations:

- `EMR` **5.12.0**
- `1 Master`: **r3.xlarge** [8 vCore, 30.5 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage EBS Storage:32 GiB]
- `1 Task`: **r3.xlarge** [8 vCore, 30.5 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage EBS Storage:none]
- `1 Core`: **r3.xlarge** [8 vCore, 30.5 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
  EBS Storage:32 GiB]

** *These are the configurations of development cluster; production cluster would be better equipped*

Comment: Hi there, a couple of question

1) why dont you use sqoop to save into hdfs and then read that file with spark to later insert it on Hive?
2) What are the resources allocated for this spark process?

Comment: I agree with Felix. Sqoop is a tool that is dedicated to moving RDBMS data to HDFS. I've had a few problems with Spark JDBC myself. Alternatively, you can also use the Sqoop Java API if you really insist on doing this through a Scala Application.

Comment: In all cases, since you are using EMR, rather then doing that in two times. Use Sqoop to dump data to parquet, whether you want/need S3 that up to you, Than pull data using Spark and performs your transformations.

Comment: As per the jdbc source for the matter, MapReduce lays on the ability of partitioning data. You don't study that part, you'll not be able to use Spark with JDBC properly. For more info, you can read this : https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#reading-data-using-jdbc-source (disclaimer : I'm one ofthe authors of the document.)

Comment: **@Felix**, **@philantrovert** we are presently using `sqoop` to dump data to `HDFS` and then use `distcp` to put in on `S3` in `parquet` format (2nd step also requires `MSCK repair`). But this incurs a lot of redundant `Disk I/O` and impacts other jobs that rely on *same* `HDFS`. In fact, `sqoop` and `HDFS` have given us so many *lemons* in past 18 months that we plan to stop using them completely. We got motivation to use `Spark` as data migration tool from [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/17/apache-spark-makes-slow-mysql-queries-10x-faster/)

Comment: **@eliasah** the thing is that `sqoop 1.4.7` is obsolete and has had issues with writing `parquet` / `orc` files in the past. That's why we were forced to employ the *2-step approach* described in above comment. On the other hand, `sqoop 1.99.7` is still not properly *documented* and *production-ready*. I've already gone through your **excellent doc** and implemented *relevant-bits* from there; but the problem still persists.

Comment: Delving deeper into the *logs*, I've discovered that despite setting `numPartitions=16` (or 32), `Spark` is only hitting `MySQL` with (max) 3 queries at a time. As a result, even when the task succeeds (because of small `limit`), it is quite slow: **~20 min** for copying **1 M** rows (when `DataFrame` is stored with `partitionBy` on an `Int` column). From what I can see in *logs*, `stage`s take a while to *start* and make *progress* very slowly.

Comment: Interestingly, only `Scala` code is *plagued* with this problem; doing the same thing in `PySpark` shows a different problem altogether. While **`stage`s do not make any progress** in `Scala`-`Spark` (and eventually fail), they advance to completion in `PySpark`. However the last stage in `PySpark` fails with `OutOfMemory` error (possibly because of unequal splits among partitions as `MySQL` table has **holes** in *range* of it's `AUTO_INCREMENT` column)

Comment: And contrary to `Scala`-`Spark`, `PySpark` was also able to *parallelize* the *reads* to the same *degree* as specified in the `API` (read) method being invoked.

Comment: **@eliasah**, **@Felix**, **@philantrovert**, could *size of partitions*, i.e., amount of data in *(bytes)* in each `partition` of `DataFrame` be the culprit here? As per [this link](https://www.slideshare.net/hadooparchbook/top-5-mistakes-when-writing-spark-applications-66374492/39), each `partition` should *optimally* have **~ 128MB** of data. *[for some reason i feel this is too low]*. While setting `numPartitions=16` for reading `MySQL` tables, the resulting `partitions` in my case would easily reach **~ 10 GB**. But then again, too high value of `numPartitions` would *overwhelm* `MySQL`

Comment: I'd like to inform that I've managed to overcome the *parallelism* problem described in [above comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149996/spark-reading-big-mysql-table-into-dataframe-fails#comment85757791_49149996). So now `Spark` is able to hit `MySQL` with 16 (or whatever the value of `numPartitions` is) queries simultaneously

Comment: @y2k-shubham, whats the solution for this question?? I am using pyspark and downloading data to FileSystem currently and yes I face OOM issues towards the end

Comment: **@Viv** see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918606/spark-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error-message/47919314#comment90700945_47919314) comment. Are you sure you are NOT passing a SQL query such as `(SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM my_db.my_table) AS ql` in the `table` argument of [`DataFrameReader.jdbc(..)` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,columnName:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)?

Comment: For the record, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002002/) looks closely related

Answer (score 2):

Spark JDBC API seem to fork to load all data from MySQL table to memory without. So when you try to load a big table, what you should do is use Spark API clone data to HDFS first (JSON should be used to keep schema structure), like this:

```
spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, tableName, prop)
       .write()
       .json("/fileName.json");
```

Then you can working on HDFS instead normally.

```
spark.read().json("/fileName.json")
       .createOrReplaceTempView(tableName);
```